# Как обеспечивается безопасность и сохранность данных на серьезных сервисах, проектах, и тп?

Tags: безопасность

Здравствуйте, у меня не совсем типичный вопрос. Дело в том, что я владею несколькими простыми сайтами, из разряда кино онлайн и подобные. За это время, происходили единичные случаи взлома, "слета" данных, шаблона, ошибки при редактировании чего, ну и в общем в подобном роде.

Так вот всегда, в таких ситуациях  я пользовался откатом. Хостинг каждый день делает резервный образ бд и сайта, и когда у тебя какие то проблемы, ты просто восстанавливаешь их, и все снова на своих местах. Конечно небольшие потери есть, но составляют они в виде нескольких комментариев, и чего-то другого не слишком значимого.

И у меня возник вопрос, как в подобных ситуациях ведут себя проекты, к примеру где есть платежи, товары и так далее? Ведь там уже откат не сделаешь, так как к примеру тот же баланс пользователей пополняется в реальном времени, а это реальные деньги, и возврат его состояния на несколько часов назад сделать не получится.

Comment: Разнообразными способами. Например на уровне базы данных. Oracle в archivelog режиме кроме данных пишет журналы наката транзакций по которым все транзакции могут быть повторены, соответственно журналы хранятся не на тех же носителях где сами данные. В итоге при любом сбое БД можно восстановить на момент сбоя. Так же используется репликация, т.е. поддержание горячей копии БД на нескольких машинах. При выходе из строя основной БД работа переключается на резервную. В большинстве современных СУБД есть такие средства

Comment: А все что вне БД на таких проектах обычно статично и достаточно обычных бекапов. Плюс наличие резервных машин с горячим переключением, т.е. кластер

Comment: Во-первых, взлом должен быть невозможен в принципе. Во-вторых, "слёта" данных тоже не должно происходить - если это обычная ситуация, то нужно срочно менять хранилище. В-третьих, категорически нельзя редактировать сайт прямо на боевом сервере. Нештатные ситуации должны возникать не чаще раза в несколько лет (а лучше вообще не возникать, конечно), а там уже можно и обычный откат применять.

Comment: В случае платежей и балансов, когда откатываться нельзя, ничто не мешает делать бэкап базы не раз в сутки, а безостановочно — вышеупомянутой репликацией, например